# Determine if HTML element is covering portion of canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a background animation running on a canvas element which fills the entire page.

Is there a way to determine if a particular HTML is covering a portion of the canvas? This would allow my animation to change it's color based on the fact that a particular portion of the canvas is covered by a (partially opaque) HTML element.

Comment: If your canvas covers the entire page then isn't any visible element covering a portion of the canvas?

Comment: Can you post some code? Anyway, I don't think it's possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways of doing it... You should post some code for us to check your real needs. But take a look at this solution:

```
function isInOut(element){
    var canvas = element.closest('[data-canvas]');
    var canvasTop = canvas.offset().top;
    var canvasBottom = canvasTop + canvas.outerHeight();
    var canvasLeft = canvas.offset().left;
    var canvasRight = canvasLeft + canvas.outerWidth();

    var elementTop = element.offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + element.outerHeight();
    var elementLeft = element.offset().left;
    var elementRight = elementLeft + element.outerWidth();

    if(elementTop < canvasTop || elementBottom > canvasBottom || elementLeft < canvasLeft || elementRight > canvasRight){
        element.css('background','black').text('out');
    } else {
        element.removeAttr('style').text('in');
    }
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/3nfkF/